# Why am I getting error 42001-214 when trying to create a table in H2 database?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, h2

I am working on an Account Service project using Java, spring boot and H2 database and the next step is to implement adding employee salaries using sql.

This is the relevant code for reference :

```java
  @PostMapping("/api/acct/payments")
    public ResponseEntity<?> postPayrolls(@Valid @RequestBody UserPayroll[] payrolls) throws SQLException {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            try (PreparedStatement createTable = connection.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payrolls(" +
                    "employee VARCHAR(20)," +
                    "period VARCHAR(20)," +
                    "salary INTEGER");
                    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO payrolls (employee, period, salary) VALUES (?, ?, ?)" )) {

                createTable.executeUpdate();
                for (UserPayroll payroll : payrolls) {
                    statement.setString(1, payroll.getEmployee());
                    statement.setString(2, payroll.getPeriod());
                    statement.setLong(3, payroll.getSalary());
                    statement.executeUpdate();
                }
                connection.commit();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("1 " + e.getMessage());
        }
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("status", "Added successfully!");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response);
    }
```

```java
public class UserPayroll {

    private String employee;
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(20\\d{2}|19\\d{2})$")
    private String period;
    @Min(1)
    private Long salary;

//Constructors, Getters and Setters
}
```

This is the error I am getting when trying to create the table payrolls :

> Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payrolls(employee VARCHAR(20),period VARCHAR(20),salary INTEGER[*]"; expected "ARRAY, INVISIBLE, VISIBLE, NOT NULL, NULL, AS, DEFAULT, GENERATED, ON UPDATE, NOT NULL, NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, DEFAULT ON NULL, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, COMMENT, PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, NOT NULL, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, AUTO_INCREMENT, ,, )"; SQL statement:
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payrolls(employee VARCHAR(20),period VARCHAR(20),salary INTEGER [42001-214]

When the user enters the url, they must provide a list of UserPayrolls which must be then added to the database. However, an SQL exception is being thrown so nothing is being saved in the database.

Comment: Put your create table statement into a string and print it out. You should see your mistake quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add closing parenthesis here:

```java
"salary INTEGER)");
```

You also cannot create this statement

```java
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO payrolls (employee, period, salary) VALUES (?, ?, ?)" )) {
```

before `createTable.executeUpdate();`, because H2 complies prepared statements immediately due to performance reasons. You need to move initialization of `statement` below execution of `createTable`.

Actually it will be much better to reorganize your application, it should create schema in your database during initialization. Don't mix your queries and data modification commands with data definition commands, this is really a bad idea for any application.

Comment: it was the simple wow.. However, now I am getting the following error: Table "PAYROLLS" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO payrolls (employee, period, salary) VALUES (?, ?, ?) [42102-214].

why? my sql says to create the table IF NOT EXISTS

Comment: Thank you very much. Also, I am aware of the bad practices used in my code. I am not sure of how to organise my code in such projects so I usually do everything in the HTTP method which probably isn't the best idea.